# Improve performance of query with multiple group by column and count function in select

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.6, query-performance

**Brief Background** of issue

We have a aggregate table to store rows and this table have currently 3 Million rows and we need to retrieve data from this table. Query for this data is taking too much time.

Data in this table increasing at 1 million rows/month 
rate.

We are using `MySQL` with version `5.6`

**Table structure** is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `source_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `channel_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `metrics_1` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `metrics_2` float unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `metrics_3` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted_on` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'posted on',
  PRIMARY KEY (`source_id`,`posted_on`,`type`,`channel_type`,`entity_id`),
  KEY `test2` (`type`,`competitor_id`,`channel_type`,`posted_on`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50500 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(posted_on)
(PARTITION q12010 VALUES LESS THAN ('2010-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q22010 VALUES LESS THAN ('2010-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q32010 VALUES LESS THAN ('2010-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q42010 VALUES LESS THAN ('2011-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q12011 VALUES LESS THAN ('2011-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q22011 VALUES LESS THAN ('2011-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q32011 VALUES LESS THAN ('2011-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q42011 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q12012 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q22012 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q32012 VALUES LESS THAN ('2012-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q42012 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q12013 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q22013 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q32013 VALUES LESS THAN ('2013-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q42013 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q12014 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q22014 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q32014 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q42014 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q12015 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q22015 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q32015 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q42015 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-01-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q12016 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION q22016 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

**Primary Key** for this table is

```
PRIMARY KEY (`source_id`,`posted_on`,`type`,`channel_type`,`entity_id`),
```

**Query** we are using to retrieve data is

```
SELECT 
    f.`source_id`, 
    f.`channel_type`, 
    COUNT(f.`entity_id`) AS act_count
FROM `test` AS f USE INDEX (test2)
WHERE 
    f.`source_id` IN (1, 2, 3)
    AND f.`type` = 1 
    AND f.`posted_on` BETWEEN '2014-11-06' AND '2016-02-06'
GROUP BY f.`source_type`, f.`channel_type`;
```

**Index** created for this query is

I read about indexes and created this index for the above query

```
KEY `test2` (`type`,`competitor_id`,`channel_type`,`posted_on`)
```

**Output** of `Explain` is as follows

```
id: 1
select_type: SELECT
table: f
type: index
possible keys: PRIMARY, test2
key: test2
key_len: 14
ref: NULL
rows: 2912247
Extra: Using where; Using index
```

**Note**

we have also create `partitions` on `posted on` date which is quarterly partition

```
PARTITION q22010 VALUES LESS THAN ('2010-07-01') ENGINE = InnoDB
PARTITION q32010 VALUES LESS THAN ('2010-10-01') ENGINE = InnoDB
.
.
.
PARTITION q12016 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-04-01') ENGINE = InnoDB
PARTITION q22016 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

**Issue** is

This query execution time is `8.39 seconds` even with index.

Also we need to apply this query two times with different date range. so it is almost taking `16 seconds` to return data.

So Please anyone can help on this how can i get this query execution time down to `2 seconds` or less.

**Please note** number of sources in `IN` query can be high (30 sources max)

Struggling with this issue from past two days.

Please Let me know if any extra information required.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: **Comments are not for extended discussion**; this conversation has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35508/discussion-on-question-by-paresh-balar-improve-performance-of-query-with-multipl).**

Answer (score 1):

`type` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '1. chatter, 2. marketing', -- Change to `TINYINT UNSIGNED`.  This will save 3 bytes per row.  Ditto for several other fields.  And for those fields that are also in indexes, especially the PK, that "3" gets multiplied.

`bigint(20) unsigned` -- If you are not expecting more than 4 billion, save 4 bytes each by switching to `INT UNSIGNED`.

Your MD5 does not need to be utf8; change the column to `CHARACTER SET ascii`.

"daily_timestamp = DATE(posted_on)" -- it is not proper to have redundant data like this.  Is there any reason not to compute the DATE when you need that?

```
AND f.`daily_timestamp` BETWEEN '2014-11-06' AND '2016-02-06'
```

Works fine as

```
AND f.`posted_on` BETWEEN '2014-11-06' AND '2016-02-06'
```

except for the ending value, which was 'wrong' in the first place.  (Did you really want all '2016-02-06' to be included?)  I suggest

```
AND f.`posted_on` >= '2014-11-06'
AND f.`posted_on`  < '2014-11-06' + INTERVAL 15 MONTH
```

Is there a 1:1 mapping between this `id` and `name`?

```
`profile_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL COMMENT 'profile id',
`profile_name` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Profile name',
```

If so, create another table and move `profile_name` out of here.

Why are your `PARTITIONing`?  It slows down the query you are discussing.  Will you be "purging" old data?  (That would be a reason to keep it.)

I mentioned several cases of shrinking the footprint of the table; these will speed things up a little because of I/O.

But for the real big speedup, build a Summary table of the monthly `COUNTs` of whatever is interesting.  Then query that table instead.  Maintain that table incrementally.  The new `SELECT` will probably run in less than 1 second.  [Mor on Summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables).

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for the reply.
First, you are right about data type. that i should definitely change.

Second, i did not get you on this line
Your MD5 does not need to be `utf8`; change the column to CHARACTER SET `ascii`. Please can you explain this ?

Comment: Third, `daily_timestamp`, Actually, for other functionality i neen daily counts and for that i have taken that field seperate and have created `index` on that i read somewhere that `GROUP BY DATE(posted_on)` will not consider `index` even if i define index on `posted_on` field. so i have taken `daily_timestamp` seperate and doing GROUP BY (`daily_timestamp`)

Fourth, I'm unable to understand what following condition will make different in terms of performance.
`AND f.`posted_on` >= '2014-11-06'`
`AND f.`posted_on`  < '2014-11-06' + INTERVAL 15 MONTH`

Comment: Regarding, `profile_id` and `profile_name`, yes there is 1:1 mapping between this, it was for other purpose but i agree with you on this point and yes i'm planning seperate table for this profile data.

Regarding `partitions`, i did not get your point on this.
`partitions` slow down the query performance ?
and yes answer to your question on purging is NO, i won't be purging old data.

Lastly, yes summary tables are one option for me to satisfy my requirements but overhead of it is to maintain summary tables so i was working on query optimization if possible.

Comment: utf8 requires up to 3 _bytes_ per _character_; a has is only ascii (1 _byte_/_character_).  Since you are currently scanning the whole table; the `daily_timestamp` index is not useful for `GROUP BY`.  Note `<`, not `<=`, which is what `AND` does.  [Partition discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).  _Incrementally_ maintaining Summary tables will be a lot more efficient.

Comment: (If those quick answers did not suffice, ask again.)

Comment: Thanks for your help on some cases where i should change my table design.
but for speed up, created summary tables.